# Make Gmail show conversation count?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I want to replace Mailbox with something similar in pure Gmail. But I miss the way Mailbox shows the conversation count next to each folder.

Is there a way to do this for Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no feature for this in Gmail. Google Labs has no setting for it. The only way to see the total number of messages is to open the label.

Comment: The "Labels" tab in Settings shows the number of conversations in each label, but it's not very convenient.